# Groupby two columns, sum, count and display output values in separate column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to groupby two columns, take the sum and count of another column as well as list the strings in a separate column

**Data**

```
id  date    pwr type
aa  q321    10  hey
aa  q321    1   hello
aa  q425    20  hi
aa  q425    20  no
bb  q122    2   ok
bb  q122    1   cool
bb  q422    5   sure
bb  q422    5   sure
bb  q422    5   ok
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    pwr count   type
aa  q321    11  2       hey
                        hello
aa  q425    40  2       hi
                        no
bb  q122    3   2       ok
                        cool
bb  q422    15  3       sure
                        sure
                        ok
```

**Doing**

```
g = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['pwr'].sum().reset_index()
g['count'] = g['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts())
```

This works ok, except, I am not sure how to display the string output of column 'type'
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion, the desired output doesn't make sense. Due to (1) there are rows which have all of its data empty, except the column `type`, (2) it costs storage for nothing. I'd suggest to use 1 row only, and having the `types` columns which is a comma separated list on the unique list of types.

Comment: This would be ideal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.GroupBy.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to set the values for columns `pwr` and `count`. Then `.set_index()` on the 4 columns except `type` to get a layout *similar* to the desired output:

```
df['pwr'] = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['pwr'].transform('sum')
df['count'] = df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['pwr'].transform('count')

df.set_index(['id', 'date', 'pwr', 'count'])
```

**Output:**

```
                    type
id date pwr count       
aa q321 11  2        hey
            2      hello
   q425 40  2         hi
            2         no
bb q122 3   2         ok
            2       cool
   q422 15  3       sure
            3       sure
            3         ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on author's assumption with merging the `type` column:

```
merged_data = []
for (id, date), dfg in df.groupby(['id', 'date']):
    merged_data.append({
        'id': id, 
        'date': date, 
        'pwr': dfg['pwr'].sum(),
        'count': dfg.shape[0],
        'types': ', '.join(dfg['type'].unique()),
    })

new_df = pandas.DataFrame(merged_data)
```